# Can't change mounted HDD's permissions at all

Tags: ubuntu, mount, hard-disk, chmod, nautilus

I'm new to Ubuntu.

I installed Ubuntu on my PC which has SSD and HDD. I followed the guide to partition HDD properly and it has been mounting without errors so far. However, I can't write anything in it.

I tried desperately for several hours. This is what I did:

1. `chmod` - Error: chmod: changing permissions of '/data': Operation not permitted
2. `chown` - same
3. `chmod 777` - same
4. `chattr -i` - same
5. Open in `sudo nautilus` and change permissions - the permissions would change but then immediately pop back to "access files"

Noteworthy, I can make folders inside `/data` using `sudo mkdir`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root directory of a freshly `mkfs`'d Unix-style filesystem is owned by the `root` user. So the first step **after mounting** is to assign it an useful ownership, using root permissions:

```
sudo chown $USER: /data
```

After that, you should be able to `chmod` the directory as required, as you'll now have the ownership of the directory. But if you are planning to use it only by yourself, you might not have to change anything else.

If you are using a filesystem type that is not Unix-like, e.g. `vfat`, `fat32` or `NTFS`, those filesystems don't natively support Unix-style file ownerships/permissions, and so the filesystem driver will apply a compatibility workaround of some sort. It might involve a set of mount options that can be used to present all files & all directories in the filesystem with specified owner, group and permissions, or an optional translation table file that tells the filesystem driver how to convert Unix-style UIDs and GIDs to NTFS-style Security IDs and vice versa. For those, you'll need to read filesystem-specific documentation.